# Why is this simple MySQL Query ordering "by itself"

Tags: mysql

This very simple query:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE widget_id IN (10212, 10217, 10218, 10215, 10213);`

Has decided to output the records in numerical order...

```
10212
10213
10215
10217
10218
```

When I would have expected, and require it to, output the records *in the order I have included them in the IN clause*.

It is as if I had appended `ORDER BY widget_id` - When I purposely did not.

Could someone please illuminate this SQL novice as to why that happens and how to make it do it my way!

Comment: that's not how SQL works. The IN clause is just a convenient syntax instead of a series of ORs to restrict the results by. The order of the items in it is not taken into account. Probably the output order happens to be the order they were added to the table, if you didn't specify any other ordering.

Comment: Default order is by insertion order (assuming no updates, deletes, etc.). You should never rely on this order if you need a specific order. Always use ORDER BY in that case.

Comment: If you don't include an "ORDER BY" clause in your query, the results may be returned in any order.  The ordering may change over time as rows are added and deleted from your table.  If the order is important to your query, you must include an "ORDER BY" clause.

Comment: SQL works with [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) and a set is an unordered collection. When an order is not specified in the query, the server is free to return the rows in whatever order it finds more appropriate or easier for it. It happens that when the server uses an index to find the rows to return, the rows in the returned results set are ordered by the columns included in the index. **But this is an implementation details and you must not rely on it.** If you want a specific order always use the `ORDER BY` SQL clause to achieve it.

Comment: Excellent comments everyone thank you. Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `field` function:

```
select *
from table
where widget_id in (10212, 10217, 10218, 10215, 10213)
order by field(widget_id, 10212, 10217, 10218, 10215, 10213);
```

The function returns the position of the value in the selected column in the given list which we can use to sort the result set.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. Do you agree it's counter-intuitive that it orders that query in the first place? Is that just "how it is" or is? Or is there an underlying reason? Ah, now reading excellent comments above, thanks again!

Comment: @mayersdesign - The purpose of the where clause is to filter data - not order it. The server is free to retrieve the results in any order as long as the results comply to the applied filter. For ordering, you must use the order by clause.